# Print directly to printer without displaying dialog box with php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, thermal-printer, pos

I have a system for a restaurant that is running on a web server and I need to print the order that is made, in a POS printer but I would like when the user clicks on "save order" button, automatically the ticket is printed with all details of the order, without showing any print dialog box (the dialog box is shown when I print with javascript and I don't want that).
I tried to do it with the php library "Mike42" and setting the shared printer but it does not print anything.

If I do it from my system in Local with XAMPP it is printed, but if I do it from the system that is hosted in my web hosting it does not print anything.

Here I show the code of the php files that does the job of sending to print:

windows-usb.php (this file is include in Mike42 library):

```
     /* Change to the correct path if you copy this example! */
                require __DIR__ . '/../../autoload.php';
                use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
                use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;

                /**
                 * Install the printer using USB printing support, and the "Generic / Text Only" driver,
                 * then share it (you can use a firewall so that it can only be seen locally).
                 *
                 * Use a WindowsPrintConnector with the share name to print.
                 *
                 * Troubleshooting: Fire up a command prompt, and ensure that (if your printer is shared as
                 * "Receipt Printer), the following commands work:
                 *
                 *  echo "Hello World" > testfile
                 *  copy testfile "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\Receipt Printer"
                 *  del testfile
                 */
                try {
                    // Enter the share name for your USB printer here
                    //$connector = null;

                    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("THERMAL PRINTER");

                    /* Print a "Hello world" receipt" */

                    $printer = new Printer($connector);

                    $printer -> text("<table border='0' align='center' width='385px'><tr><td align='center'>.::<strong> ". $restaurent ." </strong>::.\n ". $celphone ." - ID: ". $IDRest ."</td></tr><tr><td align='center'>Date/Time:" . date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . "</td></tr><tr><td align='left'></td></tr><tr><td>Client: ".$name."</td></tr><tr><td>ID Client: ".$ID_Client."</td></tr><tr><td>Order Nº: ".$orderNum."</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' align='left'>Type of Order: ".$type_orders."</td></tr></table>\n"."<table border='0' align='center' width='300px'><tr><td><span id='cantDragg'>QUANTITY.</span></td><td><span id='descripDragg'>DETAILS</span></td><td align='right'><span id='importDragg'>TOTAL</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>==========================================</td></tr>"."<tr><td>Here Quantity</td><td>Here Dish Name</td><td align='right'>Here price</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Pizza 4 cheese</td><td align='right'>330 CHF</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='right'><b>TOTAL:</b></td><td align='right'><b>360 CHF</b></td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>Nº of Dishes: 2</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>here other important detail</td></tr></table>");
                    $printer -> cut();
                    /* Close printer */
                    $printer -> close();
                    header("Location:../../../../index.php");


                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
                }
```

Here is the file Printing.php (here I do some queries to db to extract the info I need to print):

```
          include_once "../../../app/config.inc.php";
              include_once "../../../app/Connection.php";


              //include_once "config.inc.php";
              //include_once "Connection.php";

              class PrintTickets
              {

              public static function CheckOrderToPrint ($connection, $status) 
              {
                    $category = [];

                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status =:status ORDER BY id ASC";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        $category = [$result['id'], 
                                    $result['id_preOrder'],
                                    $result['total_amount'], 
                                    $result['discount'],
                                    $result['liefergenbuhr'],
                                    $result['gesamtbetrag'],
                                    $result['order_number'],
                                    $result['status']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }




                public static function CheckPreOrderToPrint ($connection, $id) 
              {
                  $category = [];

                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pre_order WHERE id =:id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        $category = [$result['id'], 
                                    $result['order_num'],
                                    $result['address'], 
                                    $result['zip_code'],
                                    $result['other_field'],
                                    $result['type_order'],
                                    $result['status']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }


                public static function CheckOrderDetailsToPrint($connection, $id) 
                  {
                  $category = [];
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE id_order = :id_order";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':id_order', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetchAll();

                    if (count($result)) {
                        foreach ($result as $row) 
                          {
                            $category[] = [$row['id'], $row['id_order'], $row['id_dish'], $row['quantity']];
                          } 
                        }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }


               public static function CheckOrderDishesToPrint($connection, $id) 
                  {
                  $category = [];
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.name AS category FROM products p INNER JOIN category c ON p.id_category = c.id WHERE p.id = :id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam (':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) {
                        //foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $category[] = [$result['id'], 
                                    $result['id_category'],
                                    $result['name'], 
                                    $result['ingredients'],
                                    $result['price'],
                                    $result['status'],
                                    $result['category']];
                          //}
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $category;
                }


                 public static function UpdateOrdersPrint ($connection, $id, $status) {
                   $preOrder_saved = false;
                   $lastId = 0;
                  if (isset($connection)) {

                    try {
                      $sql = "UPDATE orders SET status = :status WHERE id = :id"; 
                      $sentence = $connection -> prepare($sql);
                      $sentence -> bindParam (':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                      $sentence -> bindParam (':status', $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                      $preOrder_saved = $sentence -> execute();
                      $lastId = $connection->lastInsertId(); 

                    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                      print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                    }
                  }
                  return $lastId;
                }



                public static function GlobalGetGeneral($connection, $id) 
                {
                    $orders = null;
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM global_setting WHERE id = :id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                         $sentence -> bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) 
                       {
                        $orders = [$result['id'], $result['discount'], $result['rest_name'], $result['coin'], $result['address'], $result['phone'], $result['email']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $orders;
                }



                public static function GetCustomerOrders($connection, $pre_order_Id) {
                   $orders = null;
                    if (isset($connection)) {
                      try {
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE pre_order_Id = :pre_order_Id";
                        $sentence = $connection ->prepare($sql);
                        $sentence -> bindParam(':pre_order_Id', $pre_order_Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentence -> execute();
                        $result = $sentence -> fetch();

                    if (!empty($result)) 
                       {
                        $orders = [$result['id'], $result['first_name'], $result['last_name'], $result['firma'], $result['address'], $result['zip_code'], $result['zip_code2'], $result['zip_address'], $result['telephone'], $result['email'], $result['etage'], $result['nachricht'], $result['pre_order_Id']];
                         }
                      } catch (PDOException $ex) {

                        print 'ERROR' . $ex -> getMessage();
                      }
                    }
                  return $orders;
                }

              }


                    Connection::open_db();
                    $status = "Processed";
                    $poststatus = "Finished";

                    $Result = PrintTickets::CheckOrderToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $status);


                    if($Result)
                    {

                    $orderNum = $Result[0];

                    $Result2 = PrintTickets::GlobalGetGeneral(Connection::GetConnection(), 1);
                    $restaurent = $Result2[2];
                    $adresse = $Result2[4];
                    $celphone = $Result2[5];
                    $email = $Result2[6];
                    $coin = $Result2[3];
                    $IDRest = "YG84784FOSJD-00";  

                    $Result3 = PrintTickets::GetCustomerOrders(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[1]);

                    $name = $Result3[1] ." ". $Result3[2];
                    $telefone = $Result3[8];
                    $emailCos = $Result3[9];
                    $ID_Client = $Result3[10]; 

                    $Result4 = PrintTickets::CheckPreOrderToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[1]); 

                    $type_orders = $Result4[5];

                    if ($type_orders == "TAKE_OVER") 
                    {
                      $type_orders = "TAKE OVER";
                    }
                    else if ($type_orders == "DELIVERY")
                    {
                      $type_orders = "DELIVERY";
                    }

                    $dish_details = "";

                    $Result6 = PrintTickets::CheckOrderDetailsToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[0]);


                   $DISHES_NUM = count($Result6);

                   $total = $Result[2]; 
                   for ($i=0; $i < count($Result6); $i++) 
                    { 
                      $price = 0;
                      $Result5 = PrintTickets::CheckOrderDishesToPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result6[$i][2]);
                      //print_r($Result5);
                      for ($j=0; $j < $Result6[$i][3]; $j++) 
                      { 
                        $price = ($price + $Result5[0][4]);
                      }

                      $dish_details = $dish_details . "<tr><td>".$Result6[$i][3]."</td><td>".$Result5[0][6]. " " . $Result5[0][2]."</td><td align='right'>".$price."</td></tr>";
                    }

                    include_once "windows-usb.php";

                    $Result7 = PrintTickets::UpdateOrdersPrint(Connection::GetConnection(), $Result[0], $poststatus);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "No order ticket available to print.";
                    }

                    Connection::close_db();
```

This prints very well if I do it in Local, using Xampp, but when I try to do it from the system that I have hosted in my web hosting it does not work, it does not send anything to print.

I also tried creating the ticket in a pdf file with the fpdf library and then calling the Autoprint () function but the disadvantage is that I must open the generated pdf file to the printing process starts, and that's not a good 
 idea.

¿is There some way to print directly to a printer with php or javascript (without displaying dialogue boxes.)?

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm still looking for some solution. @AnkitSingh